# How to utilize username/password GET return from NoScript ABE

Tags: networking, firefox, internet-security, noscript

First, apologies for the cryptic title - let me explain: I'm at an airport that offers free wifi after you watch an advertisement. I did so in Firefox 4 running [NoScript](http://noscript.net). I allowed scripts globally to prevent any complications. the ad was over, and then I got this message:

[image: NoScript Says No Way]

I went into options and had to disable these ABE System preferences:

[image: NoScript Options]

I'm reading up on [ABE here](http://noscript.net/abe/), but my question is this: **How, on a *NIX based system (OSX 10.6.8), could I have logged in with the information provided?**

I want to learn more about how these redirect logins work... so anything connected to that idea will be a +1 in my book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the airport WiFi is tampering with your connection, making 'login.nomadix.com' point to a local address (ie one that belongs on a LAN). If 'airportwifi.com' points to an address that belongs on the general internet, then when airportwifi.com tries to send you to login.nomadix.com, ABE will assume that a website is trying to attack your LAN, so it blocks the request.

Instead of switching ABE off, you could modify the rule to trust the airport:
Site LOCAL
Accept from LOCAL http://airportwifi.com
Deny

Either edit this in the SYSTEM ruleset or disable it and add the rule to the USER ruleset instead. It doesn't appear to be possible to make it check against all rulesets before accepting/denying.